# div inside php not worrking

Tags: php, css

I am trying to style a sentence within php by trying to echo the div. However the styling is not being applied. The css is correct, I think I have something wrong on how I am calling a div withing php. Can you please advise.

This what I have tried:

```
echo '<div id="sumtitle">' . "<tr><td>" . "This is a test"  . "</td></tr>" . '</div>';
```

tried also like this:

```
echo '<div id="test">Test sentence</div>';
```

thanks

Comment: In what context are you outputting this? Where on your page is it output, is the style sheet being loaded and what does it look like?

Comment: Can you define ***not working*** ? What does exactly happen?

Comment: I see no problem on your small piece of codes. The problem is probably not related to PHP, but your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not responsible for styling.
You have to check your styles file or whatever.
Check your HTML and CSS.
PHP has nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, although the multiple use of the . in the first is unnecessary. You could just put:

```
echo '<div id="sumtitle"><tr><td>This is a test</td></tr></div>';
```

BTW: Are you using a `<table>` for your `<tr>` and `<td>`?

Regardless, the styling should work fine if you use something like:

`#sumtitle { font-style: italic; }`
or
`#test {...}`

I'd double check the CSS! :)

Comment: The code does not look ok. A tr (if used at all) should be used in a table, not in a div.

Comment: The div could be in a larger table, @GolezTrol. Please remove the -1. You'll note I asked about the table.

Comment: thank you will update you later on on the outcome, good that you undertood what I want that is style php text output

Comment: It worked, my browser was caching the css file apparently. Thank You

Comment: how about this please:  echo '<div id="results"><tr><td>Total Info: $num_rowsinfo</td></tr></div>';   How can I insert also a variable and make it work as well

Comment: You need to use double quotes to echo the value of a string. Try this: echo "<div id='results'><tr><td>Total Info: $num_rowsinfo</td></tr></div>"; If that doesn't work, leave a space between $num_rowsinfo and </td>, although I'm not sure it's necessary. See, for example, http://www.tizag.com/phpT/echo.php. BTW, you DO have a <table>...</table> in there somewhere, right? It's pretty unusual to use <div> with <tr> & <td>.

Comment: @Nick, I mean, this HTML isn't valid, even if there were a table around this code. I think you cannot say 'the styling should work fine' if the HTML itself is invalid. There cannot be a div inside the table surrounding the tr. Just run this piece of code through the validator and you'll see. `<!doctype html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<table><div><tr><td></td></tr></div></table>
</body>
`

Comment: @GolezTrol First, let me say I agree that mixing tables and divs is both unnecessary and not good practice. That said, it does work even if the validator doesn't like it! Try this: <table><div><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr></div></table> So then it becomes a question of philosophy. My approach is to try to be helpful, encouraging and constructive. My objection to your -1 is that it was (1) unnecessary, (2) not entirely accurate, and (3 and most of all) not accompanied by any attempt to help the questioner. I note, however, that many of your answers are both gracious and articulate. Peace.

Comment: Invalid HTML may work in one browser, but may fail in another (or in another version of the same browser). Since that element is invalid in that position, a browser may choose to ignore the element at all, including its styling. So when it comes down to styling problems, my first suggestion would be to fix the HTML, so you are sure that that at least won't cause the problem. That is my philosofy. ;) That said, the -1 maybe was a bit harsh. Unfortunately, I cannot change it anymore. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, @GolezTrol. You make a good point about browser differences, and I think your debugging philosophy is excellent. It was your feedback philosophy I was struggling with ;)